# Issue trying to run robotframework script on Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, robotframework-browser

Recently i'm facing an issue when try to run a task from Jenkins that simply run a .robot file.
I've been searching and trying different options from another colleagues that faced similar issues in StackOverFlow but i can't achive to run the script correctly.

Please let me show you what i'm doing, my scripts and Jenkins setup so you can understand in a better way my problem.

I have this robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Basic Test
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
#${result}    /opt/google/chrome/chrome
${Browser}    chrome
${options}    binary_location = '/opt/google/chrome/chrome'

*** Test Cases *** 
Abrir web Pangea
    Open Browser    url=https://www.google.com/    browser=${Browser}   options=${options}
    Close All Browsers
```

And i'm trying to run it as a Jenkin simple task with this simple build step:

```
robot --outputdir results --nostatusrc Test/basic_2.robot
```

But every time the Console Out show me the msg:

```
[Robot_QA_Executions] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3290544249294601087.sh
+ robot --outputdir results --nostatusrc Test/basic_2.robot
==============================================================================
Basic 2 :: Basic Test                                                         
==============================================================================
Abrir web Pangea                                                      | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Basic 2 :: Basic Test                                                 | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

To be sure of the Chrome path and this kind of things i also create this Python file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

# Ruta del controlador de Chrome
webdriver.ChromeOptions.binary_location = '/opt/google/chrome/chrome'

# Opciones para el navegador
ChromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ChromeOptions.add_argument('--headless')

# Crea una instancia del navegador Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=ChromeOptions)

# Navega a la pagina web de Google Espana
driver.get("https://www.google.es")
print("google abierto")
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://pangea.es/")
print("pangea abierto")

# Cierra el navegador
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
print("fin del test")
```

And after run, also from jenkin task with the build Step:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3  ./Test/ejemplo_Python_2.py
```

The Python Script works as expected.

Please can you help me to solve this issue? i tried with different optiones like "options","binary_location", "executable_path" etc... with no success. :-(

I also double-check that i have installed:

```
$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome --version
Google Chrome 110.0.5481.177

$ chromedriver --veresion
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}) on port 9515

pip (9.0.3)
Pygments (2.14.0)
robotframework (6.0.2)
robotframework-datadriver (1.6.1)
robotframework-pythonlibcore (3.0.0)
robotframework-seleniumlibrary (6.0.0)
selenium (3.141.0)
setuptools (39.2.0)
urllib3 (1.26.14)
```

I would like to add more details to my issue.
If i try with

```
Create Webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver 
Go To    https://www.google.com
```

instead OpenBrowser. Jenkins return the error msg:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /opt/google/chrome/chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

I expect to be able to run *.robot files from a Jenkins task (My Jenkins is over a AWS Linux machine) and the repositoty it's on GitLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right know all it’s working after some changes in the way i send the Options parameter to Chrome.

I’ll let here the code that make my script works just in case other colleagues could have the same issue trying to setup the chrome options

However i don't know why works with these 2 option values: add_argument("--headless"); add_argument("no-sandbox") ...but works.

**First way**:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation test basico
Library SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${chrome_options} add_argument(“–headless”); add_argument(“no-sandbox”)

*** Test Cases ***
Abrir web Google
Open Browser https://google.es chrome options=${chrome_options}
```

**Second way**:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation Basic Test
Library SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${Browser} chrome
${driver_path} /usr/bin/chromedriver
${chrome_options} add_argument(“–headless”); add_argument(“no-sandbox”)

*** Test Cases ***
Abrir web Google
Open Browser url=https://google.es/ browser=${Browser}  
options=${chrome_options} #executable_path=${driver_path}
```

Both ways works fine.

Best regards!